# Action not called from UIToolbar button on iOS 11 UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uitoolbar, ios11, uisearchcontroller

After adapting to the new iOS 11 `UISearchController` in the `NavigationItem`, I encountered some problems.

I've added a `UIBarButtonItem` to the toolbar of the search bar of a `UISearchController`. This button calls a function when clicked (passed as the action-parameter in the `UIBarButtonItem` constructor).

Prior to iOS 11, the search bar has been attached to the `tableHeaderView`, and this worked (and still works) perfectly. The function is called when the button is clicked.

However, in iOS 11 the function is not called even though the implementation is the same.

Any ideas what could be wrong? Or is a bug in iOS 11?

```
    private func setupSearchController() {

        ... 

        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()

        // Create bar button item with image.
        let qrBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "QR Code"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: #selector(didPressQRToolbarButton))

        // Add the new button.
        toolbar.items = [qrBarButton]

        searchController.searchBar.inputAccessoryView = toolbar

        // If the device is on iOS 11, use the "native" search bar placement.
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            navigationItem.searchController = searchController

            // Don't use the large title in the navigation bar.
            navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
        } else {
            // Handled in subclasses.
        }
    }

    /// Action for the QR toolbar button
    func didPressQRToolbarButton(sender: Any) {
        ...
        // NOT CALLED
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check the sender of the function `func didPressQRToolbarButton(sender: Any)`.
It should be like this:

```
func didPressQRToolbarButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
```

Then, you must be getting some warning from xCode since **the automatic @objc inference is deprecated on Swift 4.**

So, on **Swift 4**, `didPressQRTToolbar` or any function passed as an argument to `#selector`:

```
#selector(didPressQRToolbarButton)
```

must add `@objc` on its declaration:

```
@objc func didPressQRToolbarButton(sender: Any) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed by passing self as the target in the `UIBarButtonItem` contructor. Somehow this wasn't needed prior to iOS 11.

This fix along with festeban26's answer fixed the problem.

Comment: You were passing `nil` as the target while creating bar button item. Just pass `self` as target then your code will work without any changes.
And passing the target is required in all the versions of iOS, otherwise the button won't know where and whom to pass on the tap event.